# How to troubleshoot Spring boot 2.2.6 failure to launch application with Port already in use?

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am attempting to launch a spring boot v2.2.6 web app, but it fails with:

```
Web server failed to start. Port PORT_NUMBER was already in use.
```

The port in question, regardless of the number, is always free and no other applications are using it, despite that Spring always reports the error above. Changing the port number does nothing. I would love to hear any opinions on what could cause such an issue. The question is how to troubleshoot this problem.

Configuration:

`application.yaml`

```yaml
spring:
  datasource:
    testWhileIdle: true
    validationQuery: SELECT 1
    hikari:
      connectionTimeout: 50000
      idleTimeout: 300000
      maxLifetime: 900000
      maximumPoolSize: 20
      minimumIdle: 3
      poolName: MyPool
      connectionTestQuery: select 1 from dual
      autoCommit: true
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: ${DB_USERNAME}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
    url: ${DB_URL}
  jpa:
    database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect:
            storage_engine: innodb
        temp.use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
        default_schema: ${DB_SCHEMA}
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
    database: mysql
  flyway:
    enabled: true
    user: ${MIGRATION_USER}
    password: ${MIGRATION_PASSWORD}
    schemas: ${DB_SCHEMA}
    placeholders:
      migration_user: ${SPS_MIGRATION_USER}
      app_user_name: ${SPS_DB_USERNAME}
      app_user_password: ${SPS_DB_PASSWORD}
      app_user_location: ${SPS_DB_USER_LOCATION}

security:
  jwt:
    access:
      token:
        expire-length: ${JWT_TOKEN_EXPIRATION}
        secret-key: ${JWT_SECRET_KEY}

springdoc:
  api-docs:
    path: /docs
  swagger-ui:
    path: /docs/ui
logging:
  level:
    root: info
server:
  address: "80"
```

Given the app's structure: *( some folder omitted for brevity )*

```
│   │   └── com
│   │   │       └── my
│   │   │           └── application
│   │   │               └── server
│   │   │                   ├── app 
│   │   │                   ├── common
│   │   │                   │   ├── config
│   │   │                   ├── firebase
│   │   │                   │   ├── config
│   │   │                   ├── security
│   │   │                   │   ├── config
│   │   │                   ├── sentry
│   │   │                   │   └── config
│   │   │                   ├── session
│   │   │                   │   ├── config
```

The config classes are:

`package com.my.app.server.app`

```java
@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = "com.my.application.server.*")
@Slf4j
public class ServerApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ServerApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

In `package com.my.app.server.app`

```java
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {
.....
```

```java
@Configuration
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class RestConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {
```

```java
@Configuration
public class CommonConfig {
```

in `package com.my.app.server.firebase.config;`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(FirebaseProperties.class)
public class FirebaseConfig {
```

In `com.my.app.server.security.config`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@Slf4j
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
```

In `package com.my.app.server.session.config;`

```java
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
        SessionProperties.class, SessionValidity.class
})
@Slf4j
public class SessionConfig {
```

Comment: ..it sounds ("regardless of the number, ...")  like you start 2 of the applications!? (on the same port..but at least one c/should start, occupies the port..what says browser/client?)

Comment: I fail to see how is that possible, given that I even tried to run the app in a clean docker container, with no other services running on the defined port. My original idea is that somehow I am launching two webcontexts, but I don't know how to troubleshoot that one out.

Comment: When i run `lsof -i :PORT_NUMBER` I don't get a hit. So nothing is actually using that port

Comment: There must be a (probably tivial to solve but hard to find) bug in your configuration ..feel free to edit/provide more details/[mcve]

Comment: @xerx593 I've updated the question's description.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem. 
In my application.yaml I have this line

```yaml
server:
  address: "80"
```

My speculation on the matter is as follows: The address needs to be an IP and by providing this `"80"` string (a mistake on my part, I actually wanted/needed `server.port`) I messed the IP restriction mechanism and the exception is shown is probably incorrect or rather is too general to provide better information.